# Pandas: Average value for the past k days

Tags: python, pandas

i want to compute the rolling mean of (FLIGHT_DURATION) over the last k occurrences. Where last means last with respect to the ordering given by FLIGHT_DATE.

like i did in the following example:

```
ARRIVAL_AIRPORT ARRIVAL_RUNWAY  DEPARTURE_AIRPORT DEPARTURE_RUNWAY

FLIGHT_DATE FLIGHT_DURATION FLIGHT_NUMBER
0   FRA YYY HAM XXX 2000-01-01  11  1
1   FRA YYY HAM XXX 2000-01-02  12  1
2   FRA YYY HAM XXX 2000-01-03  13  1
3   FRA YYY HAM XXX 2000-01-04  14  1
4   FRA YYY HAM XXX 2000-01-05  15  1
```

Expecting for k = 3:

## Solution:

```
ExampleA = ExampleA.groupby('FLIGHT_NUMBER').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('FLIGHT_DATE').resample('1D').first())

df1 = ExampleA.groupby(level=0)['FLIGHT_DURATION'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=3,window=3).mean()).reset_index(name='Value_Average_Past_2_days')

pd.merge(ExampleA, df1, on=['FLIGHT_NUMBER', 'FLIGHT_DATE'], how='left')
```

## Output:

```
FLIGHT_DATE ARRIVAL_AIRPORT ARRIVAL_RUNWAY  DEPARTURE_AIRPORT   
DEPARTURE_RUNWAY    FLIGHT_DURATION FLIGHT_NUMBER    
Value_Average_Past_3_days
0   2000-01-01  FRA YYY HAM XXX 11  1   NaN
1   2000-01-02  FRA YYY HAM XXX 12  1   NaN
2   2000-01-03  FRA YYY HAM XXX 13  1   NaN
3   2000-01-04  FRA YYY HAM XXX 14  1   12.0
4   2000-01-05  FRA YYY HAM XXX 15  1   13.0
```

As you see i added a new column which shows the average value. a minimum of 3 days is needed.

## Problem:

Now i have a more complext Dataframe:

```
FLIGHT_NUMBER FLIGHT_DATE DEPARTURE_AIRPORT ARRIVAL_AIRPORT 
DEPARTURE_RUNWAY ARRIVAL_RUNWAY FLIGHT_DURATION

 1 01.01.2000,HAM,FRA,XXX,YYY,11   -- NaN
 1 02.01.2000,HAM,FRA,XXX,YYY,12   -- NaN
 1 03.01.2000,HAM,FRA,XXX,YYY,13   -- NaN
 1 04.01.2000,HAM,FRA,XXX,ZZZ,101  -- NaN
 1 05.01.2000,HAM,FRA,XXX,YYY,14   -- 12
 1 06.01.2000,HAM,FRA,XXX,ZZZ,102  -- NaN
 9 01.01.2000,BOG,FRA,XXX,YYY,1001 -- NaN
 1 07.01.2000,HAM,FRA,XXX,ZZZ,103  -- NaN
 9 01.01.2000,BOG,FRA,XXX,YYY,1002 -- NaN
 9 02.01.2000,BOG,FRA,XXX,YYY,1003 -- NaN
 9 03.01.2000,BOG,FRA,XXX,YYY,1004 -- 1002
 1 08.01.2000,HAM,FRA,XXX,ZZZ,104  -- 102
 1 09.01.2000,HAM,FRA,XXX,YYY,15   -- 13
 1 10.01.2000,HAM,FRA,XXX,ZZZ,105  -- 103
```

The column with the - before the values, are the average values I expect.
As you can see, this example is a bit more complex. To groupy FLIGHT_DATE alone is not enough anymore. There must be other clearly identifiable columns. ARRIVAL_RUNWAY, DEPARTURE_RUNWAY, DEPARTURE_AIRPORT and ARRIVAL_AIRPORT must now also be considered to calculate correctly (or am I wrong?)

For example, on 01.01.2000 FROM BOG to FRA  gets a nan because the flight has not at least 3 historical flights.

But the BOG to FRA flight on 03.01.2000 has a average value, because there are 3 last flights (01.01.2000, 01.01.2000 and 02.01.2000).

Otherwise look at the flights with HAM, FRA, XXX, ZZZ and the flights with the HAM,FRA,XXX,YYY then compare the averages, everything should be clear then.

I tried:

```
dfTestB = pd.read_csv("Example2.csv")
dfTestB["FLIGHT_DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(dfTestB["FLIGHT_DATE"],format='%d.%m.%Y')
dfTestB = dfTestB.groupby(['FLIGHT_NUMBER','DEPARTURE_RUNWAY','ARRIVAL_RUNWAY']).apply(lambda x: x.set_index(['FLIGHT_DATE']).resample('1D').first())
df2 = dfTestB.groupby(level=0)['FLIGHT_DURATION'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=3,window=3).mean()).reset_index(name='Value_Average_Past_3_days')
res = pd.merge(dfTestB, df2, on=['FLIGHT_NUMBER', 'FLIGHT_DATE'], how='left')
```

but thats not working...how could i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'grouping' columns seem to be `['FLIGHT_NUMBER', 'DEPARTURE_AIRPORT', 'ARRIVAL_RUNWAY']`

`groupby` and `rolling.mean` on each of them separately, so you can shift the result to effectively make it take a rolling mean of the previous three rows. I can't find an easy way to get rolling to otherwise exclude the current row's value.

```
import pandas as pd

gcols = ['FLIGHT_NUMBER', 'DEPARTURE_AIRPORT', 'ARRIVAL_RUNWAY']
df['result'] = pd.concat([gp.rolling(window=3, min_periods=3).mean().shift(1) 
                          for _, gp in df.groupby(gcols).FLIGHT_DURATION])
```

#### Output: (some columns supressed)

```
    FLIGHT_NUMBER FLIGHT_DATE DEPARTURE_AIRPORT ARRIVAL_RUNWAY  result
0               1  01.01.2000               HAM            YYY     NaN
1               1  02.01.2000               HAM            YYY     NaN
2               1  03.01.2000               HAM            YYY     NaN
3               1  04.01.2000               HAM            ZZZ     NaN
4               1  05.01.2000               HAM            YYY    12.0
5               1  06.01.2000               HAM            ZZZ     NaN
6               9  01.01.2000               BOG            YYY     NaN
7               1  07.01.2000               HAM            ZZZ     NaN
8               9  01.01.2000               BOG            YYY     NaN
9               9  02.01.2000               BOG            YYY     NaN
10              9  03.01.2000               BOG            YYY  1002.0
11              1  08.01.2000               HAM            ZZZ   102.0
12              1  09.01.2000               HAM            YYY    13.0
13              1  10.01.2000               HAM            ZZZ   103.0
```

Comment: oh, it works. But I do not understand .. How can this work without FLIGHT_DATE? Can you explain your solution?

Comment: Well there’s no need for the date since the DataFrame is already sorted on the date. Your rolling average takes into account the last 3 measurements, regardless of when they occur so the date irrelevant other than ordering, which is taken care of. This is just a rolling average within each group, and the shift takes care of making it an average over the last 3 measurements, not including the current row